# Migrating Umbraco 4.7

Tags: umbraco

I want to migrate an exsisting Umbraco install from our developer's website into my private virtual server.

I suppose that the server configuration will be different i.e SQL server maybe different version .. ISS .. an so on ..

I wanted to understand what would you recommend as a method to migrate the install ..

I know my way around manually installing web applications (DB, IIS included).. would that be the case if so where can i find a manual on what settings are required to manually install exsisting Umbarco Website on a new server.

And most importantlly what do i need to request from my developer (i.e. files, IIS XML Config backup, SQL DB backup etc..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about migrating an Umbraco setup to a new server. You'll need a copy of the entire web directory, and a backup copy of the database.

Restore the database to your SQL server, copy the web directory into a directory on your web server, change the connection strings in the web.config to use your SQL server and assuming you have met the prerequisites for running umbraco, you should be good to go.

Alternatively, If you are not sure that your server has everything it needs, you could use the 'Web Platform Installer' to install an empty 4.7.1.1 install, and then copy your developers files over the files installed by the WPI. Going the this route will make the WPI install the prerequisites if you don't have them.

Then you just modify the web.config where necessary to point it to your database server.

EDIT: If your developer has created any custom controls, you'll want to make sure you get copies of the source code for those as well, but you don't need the source to run the site.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options:

1. If you don't have Remote Desktop access to the developer's server, ask him to give you a Web Deploy package (if he doesn't have Web Deploy already installed, point him [here](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy)), and install Web Deploy on your own machine. Then you can just right-click on "Web Sites" in IIS and choose "Import Package".
2. You could purchase Courier, a pro Umbraco add-on which allows you to do full migrations of Umbraco sites between disconnected servers. You set up a blank Umbraco installation from [Codeplex](http://umbraco.codeplex.com), or use Web Platform Installer to get it (get v4.7, not v5, as they're incompatible with one another - v5 uses MVC), install Courier on both the developer site and your live site, and migrate document types, documents, templates, stylesheets, media, and all other necessary resources over to your new environment.